# Algorithm - Checking if number is already on list

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, list, verification

I'm trying to create a kind of supermarket software and I came up with a problem.

When I add a client I immediately say it's ID is the next one on the list, however if the list was manually altered it will create duplicate IDs so I was trying to find a way for the ID to be the next available ID. However if the IDs list is like this:

6

5

1

2

It will attribute the ID 6 which is not available...

How can I only change it's ID if a full run of the vector finds no equal number?

```
ID = clientsV.size() + 1;
for (unsigned int g = 0; i < clientsV.size(); g++)
    {
        if (ID == clientsV.at(g).getClientID)
        ID++;
    };
```

Comment: "The more you overthink the plumbing, the either it is to stop up the drain" -- Scotty, Star Trek III. Why not simply find the highest ID in `clientsV`, then add 1 to it, instead of all this song and dance routine. If `clientsV` is empty, your id is 0 or 1 (take your pick). Otherwise, scan through the array once, find the highest ID, and add 1 to it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks but how do I do it? How do I find the biggest ID?

Comment: Set the tentative biggest id to the first value in the array. Iterate over the contents of the array. For each value in the array: if the value is bigger than the tentative biggest id value, the update the tentative biggest id value with this value. After  iterating over the entire array, you now have the biggest value in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, using the size for ID is indeed not fault tolerant.

a neat concept is to use random IDs, if your random field is big enough the chances for collisions are extremely small.

for example, one could use the timestamp's [MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) or [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as IDs. beside being much more efficient than re-searching the (hopefully very large) list of your clients, it also has an enormous advantage when scaling: you don't have one authority that issues new IDs that all components rely on so that you could distribute the creation of new clients over many isolated servers.

this may be addressing an issue you don't yet have but it's a nice future proof approach

Answer (score 0):

A common way to handle this is having a variable keep track of the next unused id.  For example:

```
class Client
{
  public:
    Client() : id_(++s_id_) { }

  private:
    int id_;
    static int s_id_;
};

int Client::s_id_ = 0;   // in client.cpp
```

Using `int` - assuming it's 32 bit - without any checks (as above) means you start getting negative ids after ~2 billion clients, and potential duplicates after ~4 billion, but I assume that's not a problem....